# Archive rows to another tab greater than 3 years

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sourceforge-appscript, google-forms-api

Requirement is to archive all the rows older than 3 years and insert those rows into a different tab in the same spread sheet.

I have below code to archive rows to another tab where date is older than 3 years .
The below code is deleting all the rows before 3 years in the source tab correctly ,but it is not inserting the deleted rows to the target tab (archived rows).please let me know how to fix this code

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
const shSource = ss.getSheetByName('Incident Report Details')
const shTarget = ss.getSheetByName('Archived rows')

function myFunction() {
  const COL_DATE = 1
  const HEADER_HEIGHT = 1
  if(shSource.getLastRow()==HEADER_HEIGHT){
    return
  }
  const data = shSource.getRange(1+HEADER_HEIGHT,1,shSource.getLastRow()-HEADER_HEIGHT, shSource.getLastColumn())
  data.sort(COL_DATE) // prepare for deletion of continous rows
  const minDate = new Date()
  minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth()-36)

  
  const rowsToDelete = data.getValues().filter(row=>row[COL_DATE-1]<minDate)
  if(rowsToDelete.length>0){
    console.log(`Delete ${rowsToDelete.length} rows where date is before ${minDate}`)
    shTarget.insertRowsAfter(shTarget.getLastRow(), rowsToDelete.length)
    shTarget.getRange(shTarget.getLastRow()+1,1, rowsToDelete.length, rowsToDelete[0].length).setValues(rowsToDelete)
  } else{
    console.log(`No rows to delete`)
  }

  shSource.deleteRows(HEADER_HEIGHT+1, rowsToDelete.length)
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in your showing script, when `const rowsToDelete = data.getValues().filter(row=>row[COL_DATE-1]<minDate)` is modified to `const rowsToDelete = data.getValues().filter(row => row[COL_DATE - 1].getTime() < minDate.getTime())`, what result will you obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

Your code is working fine for me. Just added the deleteRows statement inside IF.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
const shSource = ss.getSheetByName('Incident Report Details')
const shTarget = ss.getSheetByName('Archived rows')

function myFunction() {
  const COL_DATE = 1
  const HEADER_HEIGHT = 1
  if (shSource.getLastRow() == HEADER_HEIGHT) {
    return
  }
  const data = shSource.getRange(1 + HEADER_HEIGHT, 1, shSource.getLastRow() - HEADER_HEIGHT, shSource.getLastColumn())
  shSource.sort(COL_DATE) // prepare for deletion of continous rows
  const minDate = new Date()
  minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - 36)


  const rowsToDelete = data.getValues().filter(row => row[COL_DATE - 1] < minDate)
  console.log('rowsToDelete: ' + rowsToDelete.length);

  if (rowsToDelete.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Delete ${rowsToDelete.length} rows where date is before ${minDate}`)
    shTarget.insertRowsAfter(shTarget.getLastRow(), rowsToDelete.length)
    shTarget.getRange(shTarget.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rowsToDelete.length, rowsToDelete[0].length).setValues(rowsToDelete)
    shSource.deleteRows(HEADER_HEIGHT + 1, rowsToDelete.length)
  } else {
    console.log(`No rows to delete`)
  }
}
```

**Earlier answer (Please ignore):**

Add this line before deleting rows

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance. However, sometimes you may want to make sure that all pending changes are made right away as a scriptYour code is executingworking fine for me.

Comment: I tried to add spreadsheetApp.flush() but still it didnt insert any rows into the other sheet. Also when there are no rows older than 3 years in the source sheet the script is failing  with the below error.   How do I handle this exception?                                                                                         
                            Error: Those rows are out of bounds.
myFunction @ Archive Rows.gs:28

Comment: Can you share your sample sheet with some mock data? It will be helpful to debug further.

Comment: have shared the spreadsheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bYFhBCduYYbmEE7Ksse7A2giTpq2PlLN_QphIpiOLnE/edit#gid=443731766

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I created a copy of your spreadsheet, changed two of the rows to timestamps 3 years ago. Ran the function, it moved those two rows to Archived tab and deleted from source. About the "Out of bounds" error - it was because the statement which deleted the rows was not inside IF condition. I have updated the answer with the modified code. Please try.
Also, for reference  - here's the sample copy spreadsheet in which it worked- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VJbzRmZu1uDi59vDg4IBpegbPvhNCAINP6K50EnHbIU/edit
No need for flush statement.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the out of bounds error ,now I dont get that error .But in my main sheet it is still not inserting the deleted rows into the Archived rows spreadsheet.Is  there any permission issue? Iam not the owner of the spreadsheet .Not sure whether that is causing the issue.

Comment: I think it is related to the form tab in your spreadsheet. Updated the answer with a slight modification in code. Can you try this?

Comment: Actually I had permission issue so it was not iinserting  into the other tab.Now Iam able to insert data into the other tab thanks

Answer (score 0):

## **Modification--**

1. Why do you use these lines? : `const COL_DATE = 1` and `const HEADER_HEIGHT = 1` If they are always equal to `1` then you should remove them to make the code more readable and simple.
2. I would also advise you to use the `getDataRange()` method instead of `getRange()` if you need to move all the data.
3. Also I don't understand why you use this : `shTarget.insertRowsAfter(shTarget.getLastRow(), rowsToDelete.length)`
   Because when data is inserted into the table, new rows are automatically added, so this row is unnecessary in your code.

### **You can try this modification of your code :**

```
const shS = 'Incident Report Details';
const shT = 'Archived rows';
const ss = (name) => { return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name) }
const lr = (name) => { return ss(name).getLastRow() }
const lc = (name) => { return ss(name).getLastColumn() }

function myFunction() {
  if (lr(shS) == 1) {
    return
  }
  ss(shS).sort(1); // prepare for deletion of continous rows
  const minDate = new Date();
  minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - 36);

  const rowsTD = ss(shS).getRange(2, 1, lr(shS) - 1, lc(shS)).getValues().filter(row => row[0] < minDate);
  console.log(`rowsToDelete: ${rowsTD.length}`);

  if (rowsTD.length > 0) {
    console.log(`Delete ${rowsTD.length} rows where date is before ${minDate}`);
    ss(shT).getRange(lr(shT) + 1, 1, rowsTD.length, rowsTD[0].length).setValues(rowsTD);
    ss(shS).deleteRows(2, rowsTD.length)
  } else {
    console.log(`No rows to delete`)
  }
}
```